# C# explicit cast - from collection of KeyValuePair to Dictionary

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.5

I have a list of KeyValuePairs. I normally would use `ToDictionary`.

However I just noted that the error message (shown below) has something about explicit cast, which implies I can actually cast the list to `Dictionary<...>`. How can I do this?

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Sample code:

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>() { 
    {3, "C"},
    {2, "B"},
    {1, "A"},
};

var s = d.OrderBy(i => i.Value);

d = s;
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> Implies I can actually cast list to dictionary

Well, it implies that the cast would be valid at compile-time. It doesn't mean it will *work* at execution time.

It's *possible* that this code could work:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs = GetPairs();
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>) pairs;
```

... but only if the value returned by `GetPairs()` were a class derived from `Dictionary<,>` which also implemented `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. It's very unlikely that that's *actually* the case in normal code. The compiler can't stop you from trying, but it won't end well. (In particular, if you do it with the code in your question and with standard LINQ to Objects, it will definitely fail at execution time.)

You should stick with `ToDictionary`... although you should also be aware that you'll lose the ordering, so there's no point in ordering it to start with.

To show this with the code in your question:

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>() { 
    {3, "C"},
    {2, "B"},
    {1, "A"},
};

var s = d.OrderBy(i => i.Value);

d = (Dictionary<int, string>) s;
```

That compiles, but fails at execution time as predicted:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `` 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.Int32,System.String],System.String]' `` to type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]' ``.
>     at Test.Main()

---

As a bit of background, you can *always* cast from any interface type to a non-sealed class ("target"), even if that type doesn't implement the interface, because it's possible for another class derived from "target" to implement the interface.

From section 6.2.4 of the C# 5 specification:

> The explicit reference conversions are:
>
> - ...
> - From any *class-type* `S` to any *interface-type* `T`, provided `S` is not sealed and provided `S` does not implement `T`.
> - ...

(The case where `S` *does* implement `T` is covered by implicit reference conversions.)

If you try to *implicitly* convert a value and there's no implicit conversion available, but there's an *explicit* conversion available, the compiler will give you the warning in your question. That means you can fix the compiler-error with a cast, but you need to be aware of the possibility of it failing at execution time.

Here's an example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFormattable x = GetObject();
    }

    static object GetObject()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Second >= 30 ? new object() : 100;
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Test.cs(7,26): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 
   'System.IFormattable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

So we can add a cast:

```
IFormattable x = (IFormattable) GetObject();
```

At this point, the code will work about half the time - the other half, it'll throw an exception.

Comment: I don't understand: `but only if the value returned by GetPairs() were a class derived from Dictionary<,> which also implemented IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.` if it returns a particular type (namely ordered collection of keyvaluepair).. how it can derive from dictionary?

Comment: OK.. tell me pls - where did you get : `If you try to implicitly convert a value and there's no implicit conversion available, but there's an explicit conversion available, the compiler will give you the warning in your question. That means you can fix the compiler-error with a cast` and we will settle.. if its true then indeed there is nothing to talk about..

Comment: @BoppityBop: Well look at the code in my answer, which is the same as yours but includes a cast. That compiles, but will fail at execution time. The difference is that you're trying to *implicitly* convert the value of `s` to `Dictionary<int, string>`, whereas my code makes the code *explicit* with a cast.

Comment: @BoppityBop: As for your previous question, consider `public class MySortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> { /* implementation */ }`.

Comment: just to clarify = I did not try to convert implicitly - the code was just to reproduce the error.. the whole point of this question - was - **how to explicitly** cast s to d. but as your answer demonstrates its not possible I forfeited..

Comment: @BoppityBop: The code you've provided shows an attempt at implicit conversion, because it's trying to assign a value of type `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` to a variable of type `Dictionary<string, int>`. If you're getting that error in your real code, I suspect you're doing something similar. And my answer demonstrates that it's possible at compile-time, but it will fail at execution time.